# Variable Comes Back Undefined When WOrking With Observables

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

Can someone tell me why the variable this.userDataObserver is undefined with causes the .next() function to fail? Banging my head here.

I need to push some data into a service variable that can be accessed from other components (trying to avoid using local storage).

Can someone help me understand why this variable is undefined when it is clearly set in the class?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class globalService {
//Sets logon token
userData:any;
userDataRetrieval: Observable<any>;
userDataObserver: any;
//Sets + updates user info
userInfo: any;
userInfoRetrieval: Observable<any>;
userInfoObserver: any;

constructor() {
    this.userDataRetrieval = new Observable(observer => {
        this.userDataObserver = observer;
    })
    this.userInfoRetrieval = new Observable(observer => {
        this.userInfoObserver = observer;
    })

}
setUser(userData: any) {
    this.userData = userData;
    this.userDataObserver.next(this.userData); this.userDataObserver comes back undefined when calling this function from my component.
}

saveUserInfo(userInfo: any) {
    this.userInfo = userInfo;
    this.userInfoObserver.next(this.userInfo);
}
```

}

Comment: you need to declare your globalService  at your module and your component providers

Answer (score 0):

Instead directly call `this.userDataObserver.next(this.userData)` you should use the following and try if that works for you:

```
setUser(userData: any) {
    this.userData = userData;
    this.userDataObserver = new Observable(observable => {
        observable.next()
    });
}
```

Let me know if that did not work for you...

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question: If you look at [the source of Observable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Observable.ts), you'll see the following:

```
  /**
   * @constructor
   * @param {Function} subscribe the function that is  called when the Observable is
   * initially subscribed to. This function is given a Subscriber, to which new values
   * can be `next`ed, or an `error` method can be called to raise an error, or
   * `complete` can be called to notify of a successful completion.
   */
  constructor(subscribe?: (this: Observable<T>, subscriber: Subscriber<T>) => TeardownLogic) {
    if (subscribe) {
      this._subscribe = subscribe;
    }
  }
```

That code is showing that the parameter to an Observable's constructor is a callback that's called when you subscribe to the the Observable. Since you never called `subscribe` in your code, the callback that you passed to create your Observables never got called.

Now, from the code example you gave, it's pretty hard to understand what you're trying to achieve. Maybe you can give some additional context/explanation so that you can get guidance to achieve your end goal, whatever it is.